# Python FTP Client Server & Virtual Box

Tags: python, ftp, virtualbox, portforwarding, eoferror

**I am trying to do python ftp server and client connection , with server file running on Fedora VM (using VirtualBox) and Client running on host Windows 10.
Server seems to be running but client doesnt connect to server and throws EOFerror at end. Following is the code and output description.**

one server file running on Guest VM Fedora

**ftpserver.py**:

```
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer
import socket

ip=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print(ip)
authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
authorizer.add_user("user", "12345", "/root", perm="elradfmw")
authorizer.add_anonymous("/root/pythonProgs/", perm="elradfmw")

handler =FTPHandler
handler.authorizer = authorizer

server = FTPServer((ip, 21), handler)
while True:

server.serve_forever()
```

one client file running on Host Windows 10

**ftpclient.py:**

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP()

ftp.connect("127.0.0.1",21)
ftp.login("user", "12345")
#ftp.cwd('directory_name') #replace with your directory
ftp.retrlines("LIST")
```

**ifconfig and ftpserver output** on Fedora VM:
[ifconfig and ftpserver.py output on Fedora VM snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpuKO.jpg)

**ftpclient.py output** on Host Windows 10:
[ftpclient.py output on Host Windows 10 snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrL5p.png)

I have done **port forwarding for my Virtual Machine fedora** too like this :
[port forwarding for fedora VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HltdB.jpg)

**What is the problem here ? what should I do now ?
Please Help!**

Comment: can you connect running the ftp client from on the ftp server machine?

Comment: make sure you use bridged adapter(under network settings of VM) and then connect to the non 127.0.0.1 ip address ... (ie 10.0.2.15 here ... but i suspect you are not running as bridged adapter)

Comment: Second test, can you connect and list from your windows machine using the windows ftp client (ftp.exe)?

Comment: @Charlie
thanks for replying ! :)
I ran ftpclient and ftpserver both on Host Windows 10. It worked.
I ran ftpclient on Fedora VM and ftpserver on Host Windows . It worked.
but not this woth ftp server on VM and client on windows

Comment: @JoranBeasley
I already tried that. But then port forwarding is disabled for bridged connections.
**in my ftpclient.py on Windows Host i tried connecting  to - 127.0.0.1 as well as 192.168.1.101 (as ifconfig showed for enp0s8) , but both didnt work  :-(** 
what shall i do now???

Comment: @Charlie
 can you please try with similar environment as me and tell me if there is any solution ??? I need to do it to start working on my project.

Comment: @JoranBeasley
 can you please try with similar environment as me and tell me if there is any solution ??? I need to do it to start working on my project.

Comment: I regularly do just that ... i run ubuntu in a vm with bridged adapter and i ssh into it on port 22 ...

Comment: @JoranBeasleybut **what IP address do you give for connection** ..can you send me a simple code ? 
Also,
**what are the seetings for bridged adapter** there is NO option for port forwarding in bridged adapter setting on virtual box ???